# How to fix Country-State-Select gem undefined method issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In a implementation of gem:  https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select

When i go to Post Job new page show this error on the log

```
undefined method `country' for #<Job:0x007f8c07092320>
```

I've tried to put the

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

in the job model, but did not worked.

Someone have any hint to spare?

**Job Model**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

**Location Model**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :jobs
end
```

**Job new view**

```
<%= simple_form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :location do |l| %>
    <%= l.input :country, label: "Country", collection: CountryStateSelect.countries_collection %>
    <%= l.input :state, CountryStateSelect.state_options(label: "State / Province", form: f, field_names: { :country => :country, :state => :state } ) %>
    <%= l.input :city, CountryStateSelect.city_options(label: "City ", form: f, field_names: {  :state => :state, :city => :city } ) %>       
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Name', error: 'Name is mandatory' %>
  <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'user@domain.com' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you Simple Lime, i did not noticed that mistake! now worked. thank you very much, if you would like to create the answer the question for me to accept, it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fields

```
<%= l.input :state, CountryStateSelect.state_options(label: "State / Province", form: f, field_names: { :country => :country, :state => :state } ) %>
<%= l.input :city, CountryStateSelect.city_options(label: "City ", form: f, field_names: {  :state => :state, :city => :city } ) %>
```

you have **form: f**, but you are within a `simple_fields_for` block which is currently using `l` instead of `f`

Comment: Simple Lime Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `country` field in your `Job` model. Add it using a migration:

```
add_column :jobs, :country, :string
```

Comment: thank you Ryan, but the fields are from Location, why the Job Need the Country field?